# Is there an elegant way to copy an entire row from one database to another with same schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

if you have say table `Contacts` in database1 and you want to copy `ContactID=123` to database2. Copying all columns (except `ID` I guess) assuming Contacts table exists in both databases and identical schema. Also both databases are in same server.

the long way is to list each column in the insert statement, but is there a way without listing all columns? or at least automatically get all columns.

I am looking at SQL Server 2012

I tried:

```
SELECT * into [database2].[dbo].[Contacts] from [database1].[dbo].[Contacts] where [ContactsID]=123
```

but got error:

> There is already an object named 'Contacts' in the database.

Comment: if you're not including the ID then you would have to list all of the columns in select portion of your query, but you don't have to list all of the columns in the Insert portion of the query if the columns are identitical.

Comment: Can include id I guess since auto generated.

Comment: table already exists in both databases. just want to copy a specific row.

Comment: then you use a where statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX),
        @COLUMNS VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @COLUMNS = COALESCE(@COLUMNS + ',', '') + COLUMN_NAME
FROM Database1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Contacts' AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'Id'

SET @Sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO Database2.dbo.Contacts',
                'SELECT ', @COLUMNS, ' FROM Database1.dbo.Contacts WHERE Id = 123')
EXEC (@Sql)
```

If 'Id' is an identity column, and you want to include it in the insert just set Identity_Insert on for the table you're inserting into

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Database2.dbo.Contacts ON
```

Then insert * from Database1

```
Insert Into Database2.dbo.Contacts 
Select * From Database1.dbo.Contacts Where Id = 123
```

Then turn Identity_Insert back off for the table

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Database2.dbo.Contacts OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without specifying colls, and then maybe update the id:

```
DECLARE @newId int = 1;
INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM initial_Table WHERE initial_Table.ContactsID=123;
UPDATE newTable SET ContactsID=@newId WHERE ContactsID=123;
```